# Redirection through htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite the URL like below:

**URL: http://localhost/my_site/?file_name=sample**

This is my URL I want to show it like:

**URL: http://localhost/my_site/sample**

that means I want to remove file_name parameter and get the parameter value and set it in URL, for setting this I have used below code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my_site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?file_name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But its not working, when I type **http://localhost/my_site/sample** its showing me the list of all sites present in my local that means its taking me to **http://localhost** instead of require page. What wrong I am doing?

Please help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `mysite` folder is under `DocumentRoot`. add this to your

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$ 
RewriteRule (.*) /$1/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(my_site)/([\w\d-]+)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/?file_name=%2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:(.*)&)?file_name=([\w\d-]+)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(my_site) $1/%2/?%1%3 [L,R]
```

---

For server side:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([\w\d-]+)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /?file_name=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:(.*)&)?file_name=([\w\d-]+)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2/?%1%3 [L,R]
```

Comment: Now its showing me this error:
"The requested URL /my_site/=sample was not found on this server."

Comment: @ThankingMonkey: thanks for reply, but still its not working, now its giving me this error: "The requested URL /my_site/sample was not found on this server." & URL automatically changing from http://localhost/my_site/sample to "http://localhost/my_site/?file_name=sample"

Comment: @DheerajAgrawal tats because of the trailing slash problem. Check the answer in a few minutes for a working update.

Comment: Thanks it worked, only thing I am looking for is to show the URLs without "file_name" parameter, right now if I am not giving parameter automatically its adding that.

Comment: ok now its working at my side, sorry I did placed htaccess in my_site folder instead of root.. will it work same when I do the site live say: http://www.example.com its my site domain so do I have to make any changes??

by the way thank you so much.. :)

Comment: @DheerajAgrawal yet it will. But the `my_site` folder should exist. Welcome.

Comment: no that time it will not, it will directly work like as example.com/sample/

Comment: If that the case you have to place the .htaccess in your documentroot. And change some stuff in the rules.

Comment: Remove `/(my_site)` from `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(my_site)/([\w\d-]+)/$ [NC]` and `(my_site)` from `RewriteRule ^(my_site) /$1/%1/? [L,R]`

Comment: sorry to disturb you again but I got a problem here :(: When I give 2nd parameter to URL it takes only first one i.e,. ?file_name. So suppose I have a URL like "my_site/?file_name=blog&blog_alias=its-my-blog" then is it possible to rewrite it like "my_site/blog/its-my-blog" (same like wordpress do)

Comment: Great its working but parameter name is not eliminated, right now its showing **localhost/my_site/blog/?&blog_alias=christmas-bundle-last-chance** instead of **localhost/my_site/blog/christmas-bundle-last-chance**

Comment: @DheerajAgrawal That's doable but will require some changes. You must tell me exactly how many query parameters are there. The question does not reflect any of the additional changes you asked for. Add the details on the question. And also post the last additional query parameter as a different question.

Comment: Please check my this question for the same URL redirection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494914/handle-query-parameters-recursively-using-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

try this, if it works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my_site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ file_name=/$1 [L]
```

caution: untested

Comment: Thanks for reply, but sorry to say its not working, same result as I was getting before.