# Exclude htaccess for admin area

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have htaccess like below, it includes admin also but I don't want htaccess to effect my admin area, so what changes should I do in below code?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$ 
RewriteRule (.*) /$1/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(my_site)/([\w\d-]+)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/?file_name=%2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} file_name=([\w\d-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(my_site) /$1/%1/? [L,R]
```

Previous conversation: [Redirection through htaccess not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340797/redirection-through-htaccess-not-working)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the first line.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(my_site)/([\w\d-]+)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/?file_name=%2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I moved site to live domain & removed `/(my_site)` from `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(my_site)/([\w\d-]+)/$ [NC]` and `(my_site)` from `RewriteRule ^(my_site) /$1/%1/? [L,R]` but its giving me 404 error (The requested URL /page_name was not found on this server.)

Comment: @DheerajAgrawal chek your redirection in `index` file.

Comment: If I am just opening www.example.com then home page opens but if I type www.example.com/?file_name=index or www.example.com/index; then both are showing 404 error :(