# Handle query parameters recursively using htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, recursion, url-rewriting

I am here again with the query of re-writing URL :(.
I am using htaccess for re-writing, below is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$ 
RewriteRule (.*) /$1/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([\w\d-]+)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /?file_name=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:(.*)&)?file_name=([\w\d-]+)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2/?%1%3 [L,R]
```

Before asking my queries let me give you short explanation about how above code is working. I have a URL like **http://www.mysite.com/** *(for index)* and other pages could be executed by using a parameter called file_name=page_name like **http://www.mysite.com/?file_name=my_blog**. My htaccess is helping me to exclude the file_name parameter and make a new URL like **http://www.mysite.com/my_blog/**.

Now I do have a query:

> 1. Right now there is already a parameter **file_name** and now I want to give extra parameters like **http://www.mysite.com/?file_name=my_blog&blog_alias=welcome-to-new-generation** and wanted this to look like **http://www.mysite.com/my_blog/welcome-to-new-generation/**. So if I add any number of parameter there parameter name should be removed and only parameter value comes with slash.
>      *Please note:* Parameter name could be anything.

Please please please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very interesting problem that requires recursive implementation of mod_rewrite rules. Put this code in your .htaccess:

**Update II** As per further comments, redirects `/?file_name=my_blog&blog_alias=welcome-to-new-generation&foo=bar&n=v` URI to `/file_name+my_blog/blog_alias+welcome-to-new-generation/foo+bar/n+v`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# forwards ?file_name=my_blog&blog_alias=welcome-to-new-generation to
# /file_name=my_blog&blog_alias=welcome-to-new-generation
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+\?([^\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ %1? [L]

# redirects /file_name=my_blog&blog_alias=welcome-to-new-generation&foo=bar&n=v
# to /file_name+my_blog/blog_alias+welcome-to-new-generation/fo+barn+/v    
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?([^=]+)=([^&]+)&(.*)$ $1$2+$3/$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?([^=]+)=(.*)$ $1$2+$3 [L,R]

# internal forward from /file_name+my_blog/blog_alias+welcome-to-new-generation to
# /?file_name=my_blog&blog_alias=welcome-to-new-generation
RewriteRule ^([^\+]+)\+([^/]+)/(.*)$ $3?$1=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^\+]+)\+([^/]+)/?$ /?$1=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Once you're sure it is working change `R` to `R=301`

Comment: Thanks for reply, its redirecting but showing 404 error, I tried to open **www.example.com/?file_name=my_blog** then I got this error **/my_blog not found**

Comment: If it is redirecting to `/my_blog` then it is working as coded :) As per your your question you wanted to redirect `http://www.mysite.com/?file_name=my_blog&blog_alias=welcome-to-new-generation` to `http://www.mysite.com/my_blog/welcome-to-new-generation/` Isn't it correct?

Comment: OR is it that you just want URL in browser to look like `http://www.mysite.com/my_blog/welcome-to-new-generation/` but still want the internal URL to be `http://www.mysite.com/?file_name=my_blog&blog_alias=welcome-to-new-generation`?

Comment: yes, you are right I just want to change the browser URL but want to keep internal URL with all parameters, its something same like wordpress do.

Comment: Yes I know about Wordpress since I handle some Wordpress installations myself. However now try to understand how this whole thing works. In Phase I there will be an external redirection of `example.com/?file_name=my_blog` to `example.com/my_blog`. Now in phase II you want internal forward to `example.com/?file_name=my_blog` again. However in phase I since we lost's paramater name `file_name` leaving only parameter value therefore internal forward will not have information to act upon.

Comment: I suggest you keep your external URI as `example.com/file_name/my_blog` instead of `example.com/my_blog`, which will retain all the information needed to do final internal forward to `example.com/?file_name=my_blog`

Comment: btw after writing my previous comments I have provided another answer in Update section, do check it and let me know.

Comment: Hi, I tried updated code and that works fine, but there is a problem - First time it works fine but When I just refresh the page it gives me 404 error

Comment: can we do something like `example.com/file_name+my_blog/blog_name+its-my-first-blog` so there file_name & blog_name will be parameters, its something same done [here](http://www.vancouverdreamrentals.com/)

Comment: I have actually thoroughly tested this answer on 3 different Apache installations and it worked fine on all. You have to make sure that `.mysite.com` is replaced by your actual domain name. If you are using localhost than you must use `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Yes, I have already did, check [this](http://bailbondedu.com/), its the site where I want re-write URLs. First time it will work fine but when you refresh the page it will show error.

Comment: Alright can you also post your full .htaccess in your question now.

Comment: I checked your site. Clicked this link `http://bailbondedu.com/?file_name=course_list` multiple times and never got 404.

Comment: No, don't again click on that click only once and then refresh the page using F5 or anyway, then you will get the error.
My htaccess is same like yours

Comment: Yes I could reproduce your error. And now I have to repeat what I wrote earlier, because of loss of parameter names from URL its not possible to recreate same query parameters. If you want I can give you a solution for `example.com/file_name+my_blog/blog_name+its-my-first-blog` URI though easily.

Comment: Pls check the **Update II** section for `example.com/file_name+my_blog/blog_name+its-my-first-blog` scheme.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad that we finally reached to a workable solution :)